# Existence of 3-regular connected bipartite planar graphs of order 14

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

I'm struggling with finding 3-regular, connected bipartite planar graphs on 14 vertices.
I tried starting with a cycle on all vertices but I couldn't quite get a planar graph.
Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done, try $6$ faces bounded by 4-cycles, and $3$ by 6-cycles. It can be shown that an example must be 2-connected, so starting with a cycle was a good idea.

For an example graph, click the spoiler below.

> [image]